# Encoding an Object Property String in Python

Tags: python

Getting the error: `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)` when I try to encode `apiitem` variable.

The line causing the problem is in bold

```
unordered_groups = connect().get_delivery_groups_for_season(self.division_id, self.id)
ordered = DeliveryGroupOrder.objects.filter(season=self.name.get('en'), visibility="1")
orderedlist = list(ordered.values_list('deliverygroup'))
order_by_name = dict(ordered.values_list('deliverygroup', 'order'))
items = sorted(unordered_groups, key=lambda g: order_by_name.get(g.name.get('en')))
ol = []
for dbitem in orderedlist:
    ol.append(dbitem[0])
for apiitem in list(items):
    **if apiitem.name.decode('latin-1') not in ol:**
        items.remove(apiitem)
```

`apiitem` is an object returned from an API. `apiitem.name` contains the word (été) which is what is causing the problem. Is there a reason why I can't encode it this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\xe9` is an `e` with an acute accent in **latin-1**, AKA ISO-8859-1, **not** in utf-8.  Therefore, trying utf-8, as both answers suggest, would still be broken.

Therefore, what you need is rather

```
apiitem.name.decode('latin-1')
```

(or equivalent codec name) to get the Unicode string, **then** you can, if you wish, encode it again in utf-8 or whatever other codec.

Added: from the latest comments and edits it's starting to look like `apiitem.name` is already a unicode object, in which case neither encoding nor decoding is needed since it's being looked up in a list of unicode objects.  (However if it starts with `ue` as reported it won't be found in `ol` since no string there starts that way -- different bug, though:-).

Comment: True. Alex Martelli knows his stuff. How would you decode in this case then?

Comment: Thanks so much but I am still getting the same error for some reason, that it cannot encode.

Comment: try printing `repr(apiitem)` and post that here

Comment: @natab you need to **de**code -- you have a byte string, encoded in ISO-8859-1 or Latin-1 or the like, so you absolutely must not **further ENcode** it!  Rather you must **DEcode** it first, getting text (AKA a Unicode object).  Then if you have to for some other strange reason you can ENcode it differently.

Comment: Thanks. I realized I made an error and am decoding -- but the error message still says encoding.

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I think `repr(apiitem.name)` will be **much** more useful than the `repr` of its container, and it will likely be `'\xe9t\xe9'`.

Comment: @natab, edit the Q to show exactly what you're doing -- also `repr(apiitem.name)` before you do it, and maybe `repr(ol)` as the error might also come from that mysterious object we don't know about:-)

Comment: Ok updated. I didn't use repr for it though -- used the Django debug page, but I'm pretty sure it's the same output.

Comment: Perhaps I should be encoding `ol` instead of decoding apiitem.name?

Comment: @natab, I think it **isn't** the same as `repr` -- specifically, it's hiding the *type*.  I've **never** seen a string's repr -- ANY kind of string! -- without quotes around it -- and a leading `u` if it's a unicode object (in Python 2) or a leading `b` if it's a bytes object (in Python 3).  Anyway, `ol` **does** show as a list of unicode objects, so if `apiitem.name` is also already unicode, you need neither encoding not decoding.  However since that name start with `ue` it will **not** be found in `ol` where **no** item **starts** that way -- but, if that's the case, different bug:-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `apiitem.name.decode('utf-8')`.

[EDIT] Use `apiitem.name.decode('latin-1')`. Thanks Alex.

Comment: yeah its not the same ... but simillar ... its actually latin1

Comment: @AlexMartelli yeah I know ... well it was essentially right ... but guessed encoding wrong :P

Answer (score 1):

I believe you get back a byte string that is already encoded as utf8

therefor you need

```
 apiitem.name.decode("utf8")
```

to convert it to unicode

[edit] 
I stand corrected the correct decoding is "latin1"

```
apiitem.name.decode("latin1")
```